# How can I return ChildProcess from ipcMain handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Main/Handler:

```js
// utils.js

// Export the callback
module.exports = {
    ...
    installPythonRequirements: (venvPath) => {
        return spawn(path.join(venvPath, 'bin', 'pip'), ['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'], {cwd: path.join('.', 'py-darvester')});
    }
}
```

```js
// main.js
// Register a handler to the callback in utils.js
ipcMain.handle('config:install-pip-deps', (e, venvPath) => {installPythonRequirements(venvPath)})
```

```js
// preload.js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    ...
    installPythonRequirements: (venvPath) => ipcRenderer.invoke('config:install-pip-deps', venvPath)
});
```

What I've tried:

**1) Use the raw return**

```js
// renderer (React.js)

...
// Call the handler and store its return
const venv_status = window.electronAPI.installPythonRequirements(venvPath);

// Determine the type of its return
console.log("venv_status", venv_status, typeof venv_status); // prints: "venv_status Promise object"
// Shouldn't it be ChildProcess type? I thought IPC handlers were always sync
// unless defined. Maybe I'm wrong so I tried async code for my next attempt...

venv_status.on('close', (code) => {...}); // throws: "TypeError: venv_status.on is not a function"
```

**2) Use it as a promise**

```js
const venv_status = window.electronAPI.installPythonRequirements(venvPath).then((venv_status) => {
    console.log("venv_status", venv_status, typeof venv_status); // venv_status is undefined
});
```

**3) Registering `on` handlers inside utils.js**

```js
// utils.js

// Export the callback
module.exports = {
    ...
    installPythonDeps: (venvPath) => {
        const venv_status = spawn(path.join(venvPath, 'bin', 'pip'), ['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'], {cwd: path.join('.', 'py-darvester')});
        ...
        venv_status.on('close', (code) => {...}); // these handlers work, but I'm not sure how to send these to my renderer
    }
}
```

---

How can I properly get the ChildProcess instance through Electron IPC? Is this possibly a security feature in Electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by implementing a second IPC channel from main to renderer:

```js
// utils.js - installPythonRequirements()
// For each `on` event, send relevant data through `webContents`

const venv_status = spawn(path.join(venvPath, 'bin', 'pip'), ['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'], {cwd: path.join('.', 'py-darvester')});
const main_window = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0];

venv_status.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log('close', code.toString().trim());
    main_window.webContents.send('utils:venv-status', {message: 'Python requirements installation closed', code: code, closed: true});
});
venv_status.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('err', err.toString().trim());
    main_window.webContents('utils:venv-status', {message: err.message, code: err.code, closed: false});
});
venv_status.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stdout', data.toString().trim());
    main_window.webContents.send('utils:venv-status', {message: data.toString().trim(), code: null, closed: false});
});
venv_status.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('stderr', data.toString().trim());
    main_window.webContents.send('utils:venv-status', {message: data.toString().trim(), code: 1, closed: false});
});
return {status: "Installing"} // oddly it doesn't reach this return though. return value is undefined
```

```js
// preload.js
...
onVenvStatus: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('utils:venv-status', callback)
...
```

```js
// renderer
window.electronAPI.installPythonRequirements(data).then((venv_status) => {
    window.electronAPI.onVenvStatus((_event, status) => {
        setConsoleLines([...consoleLines, status.message]);
    });
});
```